Suppose a die is rolled repeatedly. Let X be the no. of rolls needed to get all the faces appear for the 1st time. Find the probability mass function
Let a die be such that $P(\{i\})=P_i, i=1,...,6.$ Suppose the above die is rolled repeatedly and independently. Let $X$ be the no. of rolls needed to get all the faces appear for the 1st time. So, $\text{Min}X=6.$ Find the probability mass function (pmf).
I tried solving the problem as follows:
Let $p$ be the pmf.
If $k$ be the number of times the die needs to be rolled in order to make all the faces appear, then, $$p(k)=P\{X=k\}.$$
If $k\lt 6$ then, $p(k)=0.$
So, let's assume that $k\geq 6.$
Let $E$ be the event that exactly $k$ number of times the die is rolled in order to make all the faces appear.
So, $p(k)=P\{X=k\}=P(E).$
Let $E_i$ be the event that the face $i$ of the die appears at least once in one of those $k$ rolls of the die, where $1\leq i\leq 6.$
Thus, $E=\cap_{i=1}^6 E_i.$
Hence, $P(E)=P(\cap_{i=1}^6E_i)=1-P(\cup_{i=1}^6 E_i^c)=1-(\sum_{i=1}^6P(E_i^c)-\sum_{i_1<i_2}P(E_{i_1}^c\cap E_{i_2}^c)+\sum_{i_1<i_2<i_3}P(E_{i_1}^c\cap E_{i_2}^c \cap E_{i_3}^c)-....+(-1)^5P(E_1\cap E_2\cap ...\cap E_6))\tag 1$
We note that,

$P(E_i^c)=(1-P_i)^k,$

$P(E_{i_1}^c\cap E_{i_2}^c)=(1-(P_{i_1}+P_{i_2}))^k,$ $i_1<i_2$

$P(E_{i_1}^c\cap E_{i_2}^c\cap E_{i_3}^c)=(1-(P_{i_1}+P_{i_2}+P_{i_3}))^k,$ $i_1<i_2<i_3$


$\cdots$

$P(E_1^c\cap\cdots E_6^c)=0.$

Substituting these values in $(1)$ we have,
$$P(E)=P(\cap_{i=1}^6E_i)=1-P(\cup_{i=1}^6 E_i^c)=1-(\sum_{i=1}^6P(E_i^c)-\sum_{i_1<i_2}P(E_{i_1}^c\cap E_{i_2}^c)+\sum_{i_1<i_2<i_3}P(E_{i_1}^c\cap E_{i_2}^c \cap E_{i_3}^c)-....+(-1)^5P(E_1^c\cap E_2^c\cap ...\cap E_6^c))=1-(\sum_{i=1}^6(1-P_i)^k-\sum_{i_1<i_2}(1-(P_{i_1}+P_{i_2}))^k+\sum_{i_1<i_2<i_3}(1-(P_{i_1}+P_{i_2}+P_{i_3}))^k-....+(-1)^5.0)$$
Hence, $$p(k)=1-\big [\sum_{i=1}^6(1-P_i)^k-\sum_{i_1<i_2}(1-(P_{i_1}+P_{i_2}))^k+\sum_{i_1<i_2<i_3}(1-(P_{i_1}+P_{i_2}+P_{i_3}))^k-....+(-1)^4\sum_{i_1<i_2<i_3<i_4<i_5}(1-(P_{i_1}+P_{i_2}+\cdots+P_{i_5}))^k\big ]$$

Is the above solution valid?

What steps have you taken to check your result?  Some approaches always worth considering (in addition to basic practices for checking your algebra) are to solve and check a simpler form of the problem (e.g., change "6" to "2" or "3"); to verify the result agrees with known results in special cases (such as all $P_i$ equal, yielding a Negative Binomial distribution); and to simulate the process many times to obtain an empirical estimate you can compare to your formula.
